# change SciTE Compile command

Tags: lua, compiler-errors, scite

recently i have been studying metamethods, and some of them work only in version 5.2 and later. Unfortunately, even after I downloaded Lua 5.4 and changed the environment variables, IDE SciTE uses only version 5.1 to compile and run the codes in Lua.

Would anyone know how I can change the compiler command in SciTE, so that I can change it to version 5.4? If I change the environment variables, it just causes an error for not finding version 5.1 in SciTE

Comment: What is your OS?  What is your SciTE version?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff OS: Windows 10, SciTE Version 4.4.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit the file `lua.properties` (you can open it through the "Options" menu)
Insert your path to the Lua executable in the following lines:

```
if PLAT_WIN
   command.go.*.lua=C:\Path\To\Lua\lua54.exe "$(FileNameExt)" $(1) $(2) $(3) $(4)
```

You might need to wrap path to lua54.exe in quotes if there is a space in the path.